# Chroot environment can access external, but not internal network

Tags: 12.10, chroot, debootstrap

I've just set a `chroot` environment up on a new 12.10 install, and it seems capable of accessing the external network (Internet basically) but it cannot access anything on the internal network inside `chroot`. The box definitely has network access internally, and it's connected to the network, it's using a prebuilt `chroot` environment that's worked perfectly well elsewhere so I'm puzzled.

Edit: To clarify, we have a series of scripts that run to create an Ubuntu environment and then create an ISO image within a `chroot` environment we've created. The `chroot` environment should be able to reach a hostname within our internal network where we have an `apt` repository to pull some additional packages in. The `chroot` environment can communicate with external servers, but for internal connections it can't ping either the host name or IP address.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific than that.

Comment: Sure, what additional information would you consider relevant?

Comment: What you did ( exactly ), what you expected to happen, and what happened instead ( exactly ).

Comment: Added some details.